# Ruby on Rails Role-based Authentication System, how to work with different roles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using Rails 4.1. I have 3 types of users, Admin, Leader, Worker and each has his own page.
I've chosen a devise+pundit for that role, but cannot get an idea how to send users to different paths. For example, how i can take admin to admin section after sign_in, and a Leader to leader's section, can I restrict entry to some views?

Would any other gems be helpful for this problem?

Comment: Are Admin, Leader and Worker different devise models, or are they roles on a single devise User model?

Comment: Now its single Devise model. im used Pundit for role authorization. Would it be good to use 3 different models for Users? or better to user roles? in future i want to have this idea: Leader creating a project and a task, worker can only see the task and complete it, etc ...

Comment: Just asking for clarification, because with three different devise models, it would lead to a different answer, and your wording made it sound like there might possibly be different devise models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea about a gem. But something like this should work:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if current_user.admin?
      redirect_to admin_path
    elsif current_user.leader?
      redirect_to leader_path
    else
      redirect_to worker_path
  end
end
```

`after_sign_in_path_for` is [a callback in Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-and-sign-out).

Comment: thanks for advises, but i cannot say that understood Pundit, will keep on reading the manual...

Comment: Agreed - I'm not familiar with Pundit, so this is a more generic Devise way of solving the problem.